# upgrade/migrate dotnet core Blazor solution from (3.1.101 x64 )

Tags: .net-core, blazor

How do I upgrade/migrate dotnet core Blazor solution from (3.1.101 x64 SDK ) to (3.1.102 x64 SDK)
using visual studio 2019 prev 3 community.
Win10 Dev Machine.

I have installed NEW 3.1.102 x64 SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1, but it causes a fail on publishing.

```
iLLink failed with exit code -532462766   
and.

Unhandled exception. Mono.Linker.Steps.XmlResolutionException:Failed to process XML description: `<unspecified>.`
```

When I uninstalled  NEW 3.1.102 x64 SDK, publishing works fine.

3.1.101 x64 SDK is part of VisualStudio2019, when I attempt to remove it, Visual studio wants to disable all dependent features.

any Ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At this stage the solution file cannot be upgraded because the new DotNet core SDK is not "integrated" into visual studio itself.

**WorkAround:**

However one can still install the NEW SDKs and publish using the command line.
Publishing through Visual Studio may throw an error, and fail to publish, with the new SDKs installed.

The New SDKs can be sourced here:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1
or 
nightly builds at Git hub
https://github.com/dotnet/core-sdk

To publish the project with NEW SDK which was created in visual studio 2019 prev 3 using an old SDK:

1. navigate to PROJECT folder, not just where the solution file is [look for csproj]
2. run the command: dotnet publish -r {system you are targeting}.
    In my case for the raspberry pi 3: dotnet publish -r linux-arm  .

This published to the directory:
C:\blazor3\Server\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\linux-arm\publish

hope this at least helps.
PS let me know if formatting etc is incorrect, I did the rules, but still am pretty new